# Why sometimes My character rotates a bit after I stopped control input? Rigidbody.MovePosition % . MoveRotation based

Tags: unity-game-engine, rotation, move, rigid-bodies

I have been trying to use Rigidbody MovePosition and MoveRotation to control my character move and rotate smoothly. ( I mean to use it, so please, if you could help me, stay with it unless it cannot give what I expect).

The purpose is , WSAD keys control its rotation and in the meanwhile it move forward according to its current direction.
During its movement, everything goes well, but when it stops, sometimes, it will rotates a bit with somewhere between 10-20 degrees.

Is it I coded it wrong or nothing else, how can I fix it?

here below is my code:

Rigidbody rb;

```
private float h_Input;
private float v_Input;

private Vector3 direction;
public float moveSpeed = 8;
public float rotateSpeed = 20;

void Start()
{
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
}

void Update()
{
    
}

private void FixedUpdate()
{
    Move();     
}

private void Move()
{
    h_Input = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
    v_Input = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");

    if (h_Input!=0|| v_Input !=0)
    {
        direction = new Vector3(h_Input, 0, v_Input);
        
        Quaternion rotationTarget = Quaternion.LookRotation(direction, Vector3.up );
        rb.MoveRotation(Quaternion.Lerp(rb.rotation,rotationTarget, rotateSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime));
       
        rb.MovePosition(rb.position + transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward) * moveSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
    }
}
```

Comment: Note: Input flags are not reset until Update. You should make all the Input calls in the Update Loop. https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.html

Comment: Do you mean it stopped moving but kept rotating? How long?

Comment: yes that's what I mean.  but it not long, it just rotate unexpectedly right at the second I stop.  It's like, now I press W and D make it moves towards 45 degree or say northeast direction, then I stop, it stop moving as well but, sometimes it doesn't stop at 45 degree, it suddently turns to 35, or 65 degree like that.

Comment: I guess that's because of you didn't release both W and D at the same frame.

Comment: Try `GetAxis`, it gives you smooth values, so the result may be better.

Comment: I guess that's because of you didn't release both W and D at the same frame. – 
shingo
 17 mins ago      I have this same guess as wel.. hmm...

Comment: hi shingo Would you like to copy my code and have a try on your computer?

Comment: No, this situation definitely exists, the question is whether this is the situation you have encountered?

Comment: no, I am new to Unity, it is the first time I meet this kind of problem. I tried to use transform.translate and transform.lookAt to control the character. it worked better than this. However, I am trying the Rigidbody class , so ..